# search through data-name attribute content if match then show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to search through content of the attribute called "data-name" which embedded in each div that has a class of "infodata", like as you can see my fiddle below, there's a 3 divs and each has a "data-name" attribute now if Im going to enter into the input box (the search box) e.g. "J or j" or any letters or a complete name e.g. "Jason" or a full name e.g. "Mechelle Hill", as long as anything on that input box (the search input box) match to any "data-name" attribute content then show the matched div that has a class of "infodata" else hide it. Any suggestions, recommendations, ideas, clues, help, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  //empty yet, dont know how to do it :(
  
});
```

```css
.extend{max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}
.clear{clear: both; float: none;}
.bgwhite{background: #ffffff;}
.center{margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
.display_block{display: block;}
.align_left{float: left;}
.align_right{float: right;}

#searchbox_container input[type="text"]{
 bacground: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 8px;
 color: #555555;
}
#searchbox_container input[type="text"]:focus{
 outline: none; 
}
.infodata{
 margin: 5px; 
}
.infodata h1{
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.infodata p{
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.infodata img{
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="extend clear bgwhite extend center" id="mainwrapper">
  <div class="extend clear" id="searchbox_container">
    <input type="text" name="searchnow" placeholder="Search here..." value="" class="extend clear display_block align_right" /> 
  </div> <!-- end of searchbox_container -->
  <div class="extend clear" id="info_data_container">
    <div class="infodata extend display_block align_left" data-name="Jason Acapela">
      <img src="img/user1.jpg" class="extend clear display_block center" alt="" width="125" height="125" title="Jason Acapela">
      <h1>Jason Acapela</h1>
      <p>Web Developer</p>
    </div> <!-- end of .infodata -->
    <div class="infodata extend display_block align_left" data-name="Derrick Tour">
      <img src="img/user1.jpg" class="extend clear display_block center" alt="" width="125" height="125" title="Derrick Tour">
      <h1>Derrick Tour</h1>
      <p>UI/UX</p>
    </div> <!-- end of .infodata -->
    <div class="infodata extend display_block align_left" data-name="Mechelle Hill">
      <img src="img/user1.jpg" class="extend clear display_block center" alt="" width="125" height="125" title="Mechelle Hill">
      <h1>Mechelle Hill</h1>
      <p>System Developer</p>
    </div> <!-- end of .infodata -->
  </div> <!-- end of #info_data_container -->
</div> <!-- end of #mainwrapper -->
```

Comment: I updated my answer to be case insensitive

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j59dc5wv/

Comment: If none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Capture changes to the search with the `input` event
2. Hide all `.infodata` divs by default
3. If the search value matches the attribute, show. You can check with `indexOf()`
4. Make sure you use `toUpperCase` or `toLowerCase` to make search *case insensitive*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name="searchnow"]').on('input', function(){
    var that = $(this);
    $('.infodata').hide();
  $('.infodata').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data-name').toUpperCase().indexOf(that.val().trim().toUpperCase()) > -1){
      $(this).show();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.extend{max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}
.clear{clear: both; float: none;}
.bgwhite{background: #ffffff;}
.center{margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
.display_block{display: block;}
.align_left{float: left;}
.align_right{float: right;}

#searchbox_container input[type="text"]{
 bacground: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #cccccc;
 padding: 8px;
 color: #555555;
}
#searchbox_container input[type="text"]:focus{
 outline: none; 
}
.infodata{
 margin: 5px; 
}
.infodata h1{
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.infodata p{
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.infodata img{
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="extend clear bgwhite extend center" id="mainwrapper">
  <div class="extend clear" id="searchbox_container">
    <input type="text" name="searchnow" placeholder="Search here..." value="" class="extend clear display_block align_right" /> 
  </div> <!-- end of searchbox_container -->
  <div class="extend clear" id="info_data_container">
    <div class="infodata extend display_block align_left" data-name="Jason Acapela">
      <img src="img/user1.jpg" class="extend clear display_block center" alt="" width="125" height="125" title="Jason Acapela">
      <h1>Jason Acapela</h1>
      <p>Web Developer</p>
    </div> <!-- end of .infodata -->
    <div class="infodata extend display_block align_left" data-name="Derrick Tour">
      <img src="img/user1.jpg" class="extend clear display_block center" alt="" width="125" height="125" title="Derrick Tour">
      <h1>Derrick Tour</h1>
      <p>UI/UX</p>
    </div> <!-- end of .infodata -->
    <div class="infodata extend display_block align_left" data-name="Mechelle Hill">
      <img src="img/user1.jpg" class="extend clear display_block center" alt="" width="125" height="125" title="Mechelle Hill">
      <h1>Mechelle Hill</h1>
      <p>System Developer</p>
    </div> <!-- end of .infodata -->
  </div> <!-- end of #info_data_container -->
</div> <!-- end of #mainwrapper -->
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$("#searchnow").change(function(){
   $(".infodata").hide();
   $('.infodata[data-name="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show();
   console.log(string);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tnw0nojt/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //empty yet, dont worry now there will be code :)
  $("#searchbox_container input[type='text']").keyup(function(){
      var v1 = $(this).val();
      $('.infodata').hide().each(function(){
          var v2 = $(this).data('name');
          var v3 = v2.substr(0,v1.length);
          if(v1.toUpperCase() == v3.toUpperCase()){
              $(this).show();
          }
      });
  });
});
```

hope this helps you.